Transformed Ornstein Uhlenbeck process
Say I have  that follows an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process:

$_=X_t+_$

Let $_=exp(_)$.
How can I calculate the autocorrelation function of $Y_t$?

What is the distribution of $Y_tY_{t+h}=e^{X_t+X_{t+h}}$?
